# OperationalError at /admin/registration/donor/ no such table: registration_donor

Tags: sqlite, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/registration/donor/
Django Version: 3.1.3
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:
no such table: registration_donor
Exception Location: C:\Users\praga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py, line 413, in execute
Python Executable:  C:\Users\praga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.0
Python Path:
['C:\web_project',
'C:\Users\praga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python39.zip',
'C:\Users\praga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\DLLs',
'C:\Users\praga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib',
'C:\Users\praga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39',
'C:\Users\praga\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages',
'C:\Users\praga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 02 Dec 2020 15:35:23 +0000
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
C:\Users\praga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py, line 84, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\praga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py, line 413, in execute
return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params) …
▶ Local vars
The above exception (no such table: registration_donor) was the direct cause of the following exception:
C:\Users\praga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py, line 47, in inner
response = get_response(request) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\praga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py, line 179, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\praga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py, line 614, in wrapper
return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\praga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py, line 130, in _wrapped_view
response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\praga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py, line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\praga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py, line 233, in inner
return view(request, *args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\praga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py, line 43, in _wrapper
return bound_method(*args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\praga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py, line 130, in _wrapped_view
response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\praga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py, line 1693, in changelist_view
cl = self.get_changelist_instance(request) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\praga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py, line 735, in get_changelist_instance
return ChangeList( …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\praga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\views\main.py, line 100, in **init**
self.get_results(request) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\praga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\views\main.py, line 235, in get_results
result_count = paginator.count …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\praga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py, line 48, in **get**
res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\praga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\paginator.py, line 94, in count
return c() …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\praga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py, line 411, in count
return self.query.get_count(using=self.db) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\praga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py, line 515, in get_count
number = obj.get_aggregation(using, ['__count'])['__count'] …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\praga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py, line 500, in get_aggregation
result = compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\praga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py, line 1156, in execute_sql
cursor.execute(sql, params) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\praga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py, line 98, in execute
return super().execute(sql, params) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\praga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py, line 66, in execute
return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\praga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py, line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
return executor(sql, params, many, context) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\praga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py, line 84, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\praga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py, line 90, in **exit**
raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\praga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py, line 84, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\praga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py, line 413, in execute
return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Answer (score 0):

Python manage.py migrate

Migrations are Django’s way of propagating changes you make to your models (adding a field, deleting a model, etc.) into your database schema. They’re designed to be mostly automatic, but you’ll need to know when to make migrations, when to run them, and the common problems you might run into.